# Products page showing error

Tags: product, error, blocks, magento-1, template

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 813136361866

```
a:5:{i:0;s:69:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_isSecure(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3659:"#0 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/design/frontend/em0141/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(62): Varien_Object->__call('_isSecure', Array)
#1 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/design/frontend/em0141/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(62): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View->_isSecure()
#2 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home3/produdo3...')
#3 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/em0141...')
#4 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/design/frontend/em0141/em0141_eyewear/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(76): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home3/produdo3...')
#12 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/em0141...')
#13 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#19 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#20 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#21 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#22 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home3/produdo3/public_html/mafhcanada/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:47:"/index.php/men-s/full-frame/fashion-reader.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}





    <?php
    /**
     * Magento
     *
     * NOTICE OF LICENSE
     *
     * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
     * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
     * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
     * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
     * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
     * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
     * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
     *
     * DISCLAIMER
     *
     * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
     * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
     * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
     *
     * @category    design
     * @package     base_default
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
     * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
     */

    /**
     * Product view template
     *
     * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
     * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
     */
    ?>
    <?php 
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); 
    $_displayRelated = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getRelated_Display();
    $_positionRelated = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getRelated_Position();
    $_displayUpsell = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getUpsell_Display();
    $_product = $this->getProduct();    
    $_pageLayout = substr((str_replace(array('page/','.phtml'),'',Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate())),0,1);
    switch($_pageLayout){
        case 3:            
            $_PrimaryColumnWidth = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_PrimaryThreeColumnWidth(12);
            $_SecondaryColumnWidth = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_SecondaryThreeColumnWidth(12);            
            break;
        case 2:
            $_PrimaryColumnWidth = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_PrimaryTwoColumnWidth(9);
            $_SecondaryColumnWidth = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_SecondaryTwoColumnWidth(9);
            break;
        default:
            $_PrimaryColumnWidth = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_PrimaryColumnWidth(9);
            $_SecondaryColumnWidth = Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_SecondaryColumnWidth(9);
            break;
    }    
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view" <?php if(Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getSnippets_Enable()): ?>itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"<?php endif;?>>
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-view-detail">
                <div class="em-product-view row">
                    <div class="col-sm-24 product-view-top">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <h1 <?php if(Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getSnippets_Enable()): ?>itemprop="name"<?php endif;?>><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="em-review-email">
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'aggregate', true)?>
                            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="em-product-view-primary em-product-img-box col-sm-<?php echo $_PrimaryColumnWidth ?> first">                        
                        <div class="product-img-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="em-product-view-secondary em-product-shop col-sm-<?php echo $_SecondaryColumnWidth ?>">                                            
                        <div class="product-shop">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('staticblock') ?>
                            <div class="em-sku-availability">
                                <?php if(Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getProductDetail_ShowSku()): ?>
                                    <p class="sku"><?php echo $this->__('SKU:') ?> <?php echo $_product->getSKU()?></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                                        <p class="availability in-stock">
                                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?>
                                            <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
                                        </p>   
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?>
                                            <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
                                        </p>   
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                            <div class="short-description">
                                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                                <div class="std" <?php if(Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getSnippets_Enable() && Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getSnippets_Description()): ?>itemprop="description"<?php endif;?>><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif;?>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('short_des_after'); ?>

                            <?php if(Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getSnippets_Enable() && Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getSnippets_Price()): ?>
                                <?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "bundle"): ?>
                                    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
                                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>"/>
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>"/>
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php else:?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                            <?php endif;?>

                            <!--product saleoff-->                              
                            <?php // clock countdown code : ?>
                            <?php if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('EM_Multidealpro')): ?>
                                <?php if(Mage::helper("multidealpro")->getHtmlClock($_product)):?>
                                    <?php $saleoff  =   Mage::helper('themeframework/settings')->getPercentOff($_product) ?>
                                    <?php if($saleoff !== 0): ?>
                                    <?php echo $saleoff ?>
                                    <?php endif ?>                                    
                                    <?php echo Mage::helper("multidealpro")->getHtmlClock($_product); ?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <div class="add-to-box">
                                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <div class="add-to-box">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sizechart') ?>
                            <div class="em-addthis">
                                <a href="https://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/facebook/offer?url=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductUrl(), 'product_url'); ?>&amp;title=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <span class="icon-facebook fa fa-facebook"></span>
                                </a> 
                                <a href="https://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/twitter/offer?url=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductUrl(), 'product_url'); ?>&amp;title=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <span class="icon-twitter fa fa-twitter"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="https://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/pinterest/offer?url=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductUrl(), 'product_url'); ?>&amp;title=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <span class="icon-pinterest fa fa-pinterest-square"></span>
                                </a> 
                                <a href="https://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/google_plusone_share/offer?url=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductUrl(), 'product_url'); ?>&amp;title=<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <span class="icon-google fa fa-google-plus"></span>
                                </a> 
                            </div>  

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>               
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                            <?php endif;?>               
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>            
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        var form = this.form;
                        var oldUrl = form.action;

                        if (url) {
                           form.action = url;
                        }
                        var e = null;
                        try {
                            this.form.submit();
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                        this.form.action = oldUrl;
                        if (e) {
                            throw e;
                        }

                        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                            button.disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

                productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){                   
                    if(this.validator) {
                        var nv = Validation.methods;
                        delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                        // Remove custom datetime validators
                        for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                            if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                                delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                            }
                        }

                        if (this.validator.validate()) {
                            if (url) {
                                this.form.action = url;
                            }
                            this.form.submit();
                        }
                        Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
            //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="em-product-info <?php if($_positionRelated=='beside_tabs' && $_displayRelated!='disable' && $_pageLayout!=3):?>row<?php endif;?>">
        <div class="em-product-details <?php if($_positionRelated=='beside_tabs' && $_displayRelated!='disable' && $_pageLayout!=3):?>col-sm-18 first<?php endif;?>">

            <div class="emtabs-below-image em-line-01 em-details-tabs product-collateral">
                <div class="em-details-tabs-content">
                    <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
                    <div class="box-collateral em-line-01 <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
                        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
                        <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        <?php echo $html; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_collateral') ?> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if($_positionRelated=='top_tabs'):?>
            <?php if($_displayRelated!='disable'):?>
                <?php if($_displayRelated=='replace' || ( $_displayRelated=='replace_empty' && !($this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related.content'))) ):?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('replace.related') ?>
                <?php else:?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related.content') ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif;?>              

            <?php if($_displayUpsell!='disable'):?>
                <?php if($_displayUpsell=='replace' || ( $_displayUpsell=='replace_empty' && !($this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'))) ):?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('replace.upsell') ?>
                <?php else:?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>
        </div>

        <?php if($_positionRelated=='beside_tabs' && $_displayRelated!='disable' && $_pageLayout!=3):?>
            <div class="em-product-info-right col-sm-6 last">
                <?php if($_displayRelated=='replace' || ( $_displayRelated=='replace_empty' && !($this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related.content'))) ):?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('replace.related') ?>
                <?php else:?>
                     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related.content') ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the content of `app/design/frontend/em0141/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism it has so many lines

Comment: Post line 50 to 70

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting in the comments

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism oops sorry brother . i'm really confused

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism have you got any solution ?

Comment: Yes see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`_isSecure` method was introduced in Magento 1.9.2.0** so I assume you're using a version prior to this.

To fix your issue you can replace (line 62 of `app/design/frontend/em0141/default/template/catalog/product/‌​view.phtml`):

```
<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>
```

Comment: i'm using 1.9.0.1

Comment: @rameez.hashmi that's why you got this error. The template is not compatible with 1.9.0.1. My answer will fix your issue

Comment: i added this line  <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => true)) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

Comment: and now its working